How to loop through nested object maps in terraform?
I'd like the resource below to ingest a variable/local containing nested object maps.
Resource:
resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_firewall_rule" "pgsql_fw_rules" {
  for_each = ???
  server_id        = module.pgsql[each.key].id
  name             = ???
  start_ip_address = ???
  end_ip_address   = ???
}

Variable/local:
  + output1 = {
      + aa1 = {
          + azure_services = {
              + end_ip   = "0.0.0.0"
              + start_ip = "0.0.0.0"
            }
          + rule2          = {
              + end_ip   = "10.255.255.255"
              + start_ip = "10.0.0.1"
            }
          + ruleabc        = {
              + end_ip   = "1.1.1.2"
              + start_ip = "1.1.1.1"
            }
          + tf_user        = {
              + end_ip   = "127.0.0.2"
              + start_ip = "127.0.0.1"
            }
        }
      + aa2 = {
          + azure_services = {
              + end_ip   = "0.0.0.0"
              + start_ip = "0.0.0.0"
            }
          + rulexyz        = {
              + end_ip   = "1.1.1.2"
              + start_ip = "1.1.1.1"
            }
          + tf_user        = {
              + end_ip   = "127.0.0.2"
              + start_ip = "127.0.0.1"
            }
        }
    }

As you can see from the resource above, I'm unsure how to access each object map's contents and this is what I would like some help with.
Here's a few restrictions though:

the each.key statement inside the resource must be the customer's name (aa1, aa2, etc.) - the first map's key
I cannot change the original variable/local named output1, so the issue must be either resolved from within the resource for_each (preferably) or with the creation of another local

I assume that:

a for_each with a nested for could do trick, although the logic to build it escapes me
there could be an easy (magical :-/) way to refer to those inner map strings, e.g. each.[*].value.start_ip

Any ideas?

Where is that output value coming from?

To make things easier you can:

Flatten all the rules
Create a map with a custom key such as ${server_name}-${rule_name}
Finally, iterate over the map for_each in the resource you want to manage

Working example:
locals {
  output1 = {
    aa1 = {
      azure_services = {
        end_ip   = "0.0.0.0"
        start_ip = "0.0.0.0"
      }
      rule2 = {
        end_ip   = "10.255.255.255"
        start_ip = "10.0.0.1"
      }
      ruleabc = {
        end_ip   = "1.1.1.2"
        start_ip = "1.1.1.1"
      }
      tf_user = {
        end_ip   = "127.0.0.2"
        start_ip = "127.0.0.1"
      }
    }
    aa2 = {
      azure_services = {
        end_ip   = "0.0.0.0"
        start_ip = "0.0.0.0"
      }
      rulexyz = {
        end_ip   = "1.1.1.2"
        start_ip = "1.1.1.1"
      }
      tf_user = {
        end_ip   = "127.0.0.2"
        start_ip = "127.0.0.1"
      }
    }
  }

  flattened_rules = flatten([
    for server_name, rules in local.output1 : [
      for rule_name, details in rules : {
        server_name = server_name
        rule_name   = rule_name
        start_ip    = details.start_ip
        end_ip      = details.end_ip
      }
    ]
  ])

  # Create a map with key as "${server_name}-${rule_name}" and value as the rule details
  rules_map = {
    for rule in local.flattened_rules : "${rule.server_name}-${rule.rule_name}" => rule
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "example" {
  for_each = local.rules_map

  triggers = {
    server_name = each.value.server_name
    rule_name   = each.value.rule_name
    start_ip    = each.value.start_ip
    end_ip      = each.value.end_ip
  }
}

Running terraform plan:

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # null_resource.example["aa1-azure_services"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "example" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "end_ip"      = "0.0.0.0"
          + "rule_name"   = "azure_services"
          + "server_name" = "aa1"
          + "start_ip"    = "0.0.0.0"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.example["aa1-rule2"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "example" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "end_ip"      = "10.255.255.255"
          + "rule_name"   = "rule2"
          + "server_name" = "aa1"
          + "start_ip"    = "10.0.0.1"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.example["aa1-ruleabc"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "example" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "end_ip"      = "1.1.1.2"
          + "rule_name"   = "ruleabc"
          + "server_name" = "aa1"
          + "start_ip"    = "1.1.1.1"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.example["aa1-tf_user"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "example" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "end_ip"      = "127.0.0.2"
          + "rule_name"   = "tf_user"
          + "server_name" = "aa1"
          + "start_ip"    = "127.0.0.1"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.example["aa2-azure_services"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "example" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "end_ip"      = "0.0.0.0"
          + "rule_name"   = "azure_services"
          + "server_name" = "aa2"
          + "start_ip"    = "0.0.0.0"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.example["aa2-rulexyz"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "example" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "end_ip"      = "1.1.1.2"
          + "rule_name"   = "rulexyz"
          + "server_name" = "aa2"
          + "start_ip"    = "1.1.1.1"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.example["aa2-tf_user"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "example" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "end_ip"      = "127.0.0.2"
          + "rule_name"   = "tf_user"
          + "server_name" = "aa2"
          + "start_ip"    = "127.0.0.1"
        }
    }

Plan: 7 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.


I think something like this should work if there is a local variable named output1:
locals {
  output1 = {
    aa1 = {
      azure_services = {
        end_ip   = "0.0.0.0"
        start_ip = "0.0.0.0"
      }
      rule2 = {
        end_ip   = "10.255.255.255"
        start_ip = "10.0.0.1"
      }
      ruleabc = {
        end_ip   = "1.1.1.2"
        start_ip = "1.1.1.1"
      }
      tf_user = {
        end_ip   = "127.0.0.2"
        start_ip = "127.0.0.1"
      }
    }
    aa2 = {
      azure_services = {
        end_ip   = "0.0.0.0"
        start_ip = "0.0.0.0"
      }
      rulexyz = {
        end_ip   = "1.1.1.2"
        start_ip = "1.1.1.1"
      }
      tf_user = {
        end_ip   = "127.0.0.2"
        start_ip = "127.0.0.1"
      }
    }
  }

  fw_rules = merge(flatten([
    for client, services in local.output1 : {
      for service_name, ip in services :
      "${client}-${service_name}" => {
        "client"   = client
        "start_ip" = ip.start_ip
        "end_ip"   = ip.end_ip
      }
  }])...) # this is the ellipsis operator, do not remove it
}

The above gives the following output:
> local.fw_rules
{
  "aa1-azure_services" = {
    "client" = "aa1"
    "end_ip" = "0.0.0.0"
    "start_ip" = "0.0.0.0"
  }
  "aa1-rule2" = {
    "client" = "aa1"
    "end_ip" = "10.255.255.255"
    "start_ip" = "10.0.0.1"
  }
  "aa1-ruleabc" = {
    "client" = "aa1"
    "end_ip" = "1.1.1.2"
    "start_ip" = "1.1.1.1"
  }
  "aa1-tf_user" = {
    "client" = "aa1"
    "end_ip" = "127.0.0.2"
    "start_ip" = "127.0.0.1"
  }
  "aa2-azure_services" = {
    "client" = "aa2"
    "end_ip" = "0.0.0.0"
    "start_ip" = "0.0.0.0"
  }
  "aa2-rulexyz" = {
    "client" = "aa2"
    "end_ip" = "1.1.1.2"
    "start_ip" = "1.1.1.1"
  }
  "aa2-tf_user" = {
    "client" = "aa2"
    "end_ip" = "127.0.0.2"
    "start_ip" = "127.0.0.1"
  }
}

Now, the last part is only applying the new local variable to the resource:
resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_firewall_rule" "pgsql_fw_rules" {
  for_each         = local.fw_rules
  server_id        = module.pgsql[each.value.client].id
  name             = each.value.client
  start_ip_address = each.value.start_ip
  end_ip_address   = each.value.end_ip
}

